# How do I receive an email whenever someone leaves a review for my Android app?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to receive an email whenever someone leaves a review for my Android app so that I can reply, if needed.  I'm not seeing a setting for that in the Google play settings... Is this possible?

I know I could build something to [programmatically check](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), but I'd prefer not to re-invent the wheel, and this seems like something that there would just be a setting for somewhere, or that would just happen automatically...

Answer (score 1):

there is no official api unfortunately - but you can have a look at https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics - with this you can do what you want

Comment: gsutil is an official api and, according to google, it can access ratings and reviews. The Andlytcs app seems pretty slick too, but looks a little more fragile, since it doesn't use a public API.

Comment: @Troy the problem with the data behind gsutil is that it is not very current - only updated once a month AFAIK - so not really an option in my opinion

Comment: Is that what you're finding from testing (once a month), or is that what you're finding from gsutil documentation?  I'm not all that familiar with gsutil, I just noticed that that's what google points me to from the reviews page in google play...

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any such option either. I think using gsutil is your only option at this point.